# What is the refutation of this article about the FED being privately owned

Tags: federal-reserve, nonexpert

What is the refutation of this article about the FED being privately owned

I find this [article](https://www.facts-are-facts.com/news/the-federal-reserve-is-privately-owned) and I would like to know what is the refutation.

Please proper academic arguments.

Comment: It's common knowledge that the federal reserve banks are set up like private corporations. Member banks hold stock in the Federal Reserve Banks and earn dividends.

Comment: @Alex common knowlenge, depending where, between Libertarians yes, between normies no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no refutation of the claim.

Fed is a privately owned despite it being a government institution.

Fed clearly states this on its own [website](https://www.stlouisfed.org/in-plain-english/who-owns-the-federal-reserve-banks):

> The Federal Reserve Banks are not a part of the federal government, but they exist because of an act of Congress. Their purpose is to serve the public. So is the Fed private or public?

> The answer is both. While the Board of Governors is an independent government agency, the Federal Reserve Banks are set up like private corporations. Member banks hold stock in the Federal Reserve Banks and earn dividends. Holding this stock does not carry with it the control and financial interest given to holders of common stock in for-profit organizations. The stock may not be sold or pledged as collateral for loans. Member banks also elect six of the nine members of each Bank's board of directors.

However, note despite of private ownership:

- the Chairman of Fed is publicly selected by president.
- private banks are actually forced to own Fed, and have no say in how Fed is being run, and the return on the capital they are forced to invest in Fed is also not really lucrative.